# Running jQuery function only for one form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two forms in my template. I have a simple jQuery function that I would like to run only for one form. My template looks something like this

```
<form id="form" name="form" method="POST">
[...]
</form>

<form id="form2" name="form2" method="POST">
[...]
</form>
```

Now I would like my jQuery function with the progress bar to work only on one form. Not for two. How can I do this?

My jQuery function

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('form').on('submit', function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);

    $.ajax({
      xhr: function() {
        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e) {

          if (e.lengthComputable) {

            console.log('Bytes Loaded: ' + e.loaded);
            console.log('Total Size: ' + e.total);
            console.log('Percentage Uploaded: ' + (e.loaded / e.total))

            var percent = Math.round((e.loaded / e.total) * 100);

            $('#progressBar').attr('aria-valuenow', percent).css('width', percent + '%').text(percent + '%');

          }

        });

        return xhr;
      },
      type: 'POST',
      url: '',
      data: formData,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      success: function() {
        location.reload();
      }
    });

  });

  $("#form").submit(function(e) {
    $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
    return false;
  });

});
```

I tried to grab her using ID `$('#form').('form').on('submit', function(event)` but I can't achieve my result.

Comment: Learn jQuery Selectors, or better yet, just use raw JavaScript now that there's `documentOrElement.querySelector()` and `documentOrElement.querySelectorAll()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just using `$('#form').on('submit', ...)` should work just fine. `$('#form').('form')` is not valid syntax. Since element with id `#form` is a `<form>` tag you already have the form when selecting by id.